# Image extends beyond the parent in Twitter Bootstrap in spite of `img-responsive`

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Twitter's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) states that "Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element."

This is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li role="navigation" class="active"><a href="#">NavA</a></li>
        <li role="navigation"><a href="#">NavB</a></li>
        <li role="navigation"><a href="#">NavC</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The only way, however, that I can get the image not to extend beyond its parent is to modify CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

I am new to Bootstrap but my understanding is that it is better to extend its core code rather than override it. To me, adding the class `img-responsive` should do what it says– scale the image nicely to the parent element.

[Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/TMHOwjDmEp) for your reference. [EDIT] Be sure to comment out my CSS override to see what I am talking about.

What am I missing? Or is my modification considered standard practice?

Comment: @Lee Sorry, I was not very clear. You need to comment out my CSS override in the fiddle to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.navbar-brand` doesn't have a width set by default, so `.img-responsive` has no idea what the parent width should be, and so cannot scale to it.

By default if no width or height attributes are added to an `<img>` tag, the image is displayed at full size.

Your modification is correct. Or you can just apply a max-width to the `.navbar-brand`.

http://www.bootply.com/BGsm04iKKK

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the class `img-responsive` works in Bootstrap unless it's being used inside of the `Bootstrap Grid`.

According to the documentation on how to use an image for the `navbar-brand`, you may need to customize the CSS depending on your image.

> Replace the navbar brand with your own image by swapping the text for an `<img>`. Since the .navbar-brand has its own padding and height, you may need to override some CSS depending on your image.

[Source](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image)